# Diagonal line in table with vertical text

Tags: tables, rotating, height

I want to add a diagonal line in a the top line of a table where the other entries on the first row are written sideways. I've tried \backslashbox and \diagbox and \diag but no matter how I change the values the topmost position of the line does not increase without lifting all the other entries.

```
\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Pugh matrix}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline\hline
\backslashbox[130pt]{Property}{Concept} & \begin{sideways} Concept 1 \end{sideways} &  \begin{sideways} Next concept \end{sideways} & 
\begin{sideways} Next concept/increase line{\ }  \end{sideways} \\
\hline
Do this                & 0 & 0 & - \\
Do that     & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
Do it quickly   & 0 & + & + \\
Do the task quickly         & 0 & 0 & - \\ 
\hline 
SUM:                        & 0 & +1 & +2 \\
\hline
Ranking                     & 2 & 2 & 1  \\
\hline
Keep                        & NO & NO & YES \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:Pugh_matrix2}
\end{table}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

I used `diagbox` instead of `slashbox` and the `rotatebox` macro from `graphicx` instead of the `rotating` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Pugh matrix}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline\hline
\diagbox[dir=NW]{\rule{0mm}{4cm}Property}{Concept} & \rotatebox[x=2cm]{90}{Concept 1} & \rotatebox[x=2cm]{90}{Next concept} & 
\rotatebox[x=2cm]{90}{Next concept/increase line\ } \\
\hline
Do this                & 0 & 0 & - \\
Do that     & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
Do it quickly   & 0 & + & + \\
Do the task quickly         & 0 & 0 & - \\ 
\hline 
SUM:                        & 0 & +1 & +2 \\
\hline
Ranking                     & 2 & 2 & 1  \\
\hline
Keep                        & NO & NO & YES \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:Pugh_matrix2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose another solution, based on the `\rotcell` command from `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in cells. Also various improvements to the table, in particular vertical padding between caption and table thanks to the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, caption, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering\settowidth\rotheadsize{Next concept/}
  \renewcommand\cellalign{cl}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \caption{Pugh matrix}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c}
    \toprule\noalign{\vskip-1pt}\hline
    \diagbox[height=1.25\rotheadsize]{\raisebox{3ex}{Property}}{\raisebox{-4ex}{Concept}} & \rotcell{Concept 1} & \rotcell{Next concept} & \rotcell{Next concept/ \\increase line} \\
    \hline
    Do this & 0 & 0 & $ - $ \\
    Do that & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    Do it quickly & 0 & + & + \\
    Do the task quickly & 0 & 0 & $ - $ \\
    \hline
    SUM: & 0 & +1 & +2 \\
    \hline
    Ranking & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
    \hline
    Keep & NO & NO & YES \\
    \hline\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:Pugh_matrix2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\diagbox`. With that tool, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Pugh matrix}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}[vlines]
\hline
\diagbox{Property}{Concept} & 
\RowStyle[cell-space-top-limit=3pt]{\rotate}
Concept 1 & Next concept & Next concept/increase line  \\
\hline
Do this                & $0$ & $0$  & $-$ \\
Do that                & $0$ & $0$  & $0$ \\
Do it quickly          & $0$ & $+$  & $+$ \\
Do the task quickly    & $0$ & $0$  & $-$ \\ 
\hline 
SUM:                   & $0$ & $+1$ & $+2$ \\
\hline
Ranking                & $2$ & $2$  & $1$  \\
\hline
Keep                   & NO  & NO   & YES \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{tab:Pugh_matrix2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you actually want to put double rules above and below the tabular, there will be a small issue. If you use `\hline\hline` for the double rule above the table, the top-left position of the diagonal rule won't be correct. That's why, in the following code, I have drawn the first rule above the tabular with Tikz (using PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,caption,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Pugh matrix}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}[vlines]
\Hline
\diagbox{Property}{Concept} & 
\RowStyle[cell-space-top-limit=3pt]{\rotate}
Concept 1 & Next concept & Next concept/increase line  \\
\Hline
Do this                & $0$ & $0$  & $-$ \\
Do that                & $0$ & $0$  & $0$ \\
Do it quickly          & $0$ & $+$  & $+$ \\
Do the task quickly    & $0$ & $0$  & $-$ \\ 
\Hline 
SUM:                   & $0$ & $+1$ & $+2$ \\
\Hline
Ranking                & $2$ & $2$  & $1$  \\
\Hline
Keep                   & NO  & NO   & YES \\
\Hline
\Hline
\CodeAfter
   \tikz \draw ([yshift=\doublerulesep]1-|1) -- ([yshift=\doublerulesep]1-|last)  ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{tab:Pugh_matrix2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]