# Adjust diagbox diagonal line

Tags: tables

I am using `diagbox` the problem is that I have images in header, that are larger the shape of the `diagbox`cell, which makes the diagonal line and shape of the `diagbox` cell incorrect. How can I do to make the diagonal line start from the top left side?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline 
\diagbox {Product}{Feature}
&  \includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/7HeadLegsNoGlasses} &
\includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/6Eyes} &
 \includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/4Eyeglasses}  & 
\includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/3Jacket} &
\includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/1Shirtsleeves} & 
\includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/2Shirtbody} &
\includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/5Hands} &
\includegraphics[width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/8Stripedshirt} \\
\hline
\includegraphics[align=c,width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/shirtperson}
 & \checkmark & \checkmark &   &  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &  \\
\hline
\includegraphics[align=c,width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/shirtjacketperson}
 & \checkmark & \checkmark &   & \checkmark &  & \checkmark &  & \\
\hline
\includegraphics[align=c,width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/shirtjacketglassesperson}
 & \checkmark &  & \checkmark  & \checkmark &  & \checkmark &  &  \\
\hline
\includegraphics[align=c,width=.07\linewidth]
{figures/stripedshirtperson}
& \checkmark & \checkmark & &  &  &  & \checkmark & \checkmark\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table to test captions and labels}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the output]

### Edit by [ManuelKuehner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14649/dr-manuel-kuehner)

*I propose this MWE*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

% Code based on *diagbox* manual example code 
\begin{tabular}{|l|ccc|}
\hline
\diagbox{Time}{Day} & \includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-a} & Tue & Wed \\
\hline
Morning & used & used & \\
Afternoon & & used & used \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269252