# \diagbox misbehaving in multicolumn and multirow

Tags: multicolumn, multirow, diagbox

I am trying to generate a table based on this diagram here:

[image: Risk Matrix Table Figure]

I based my LaTeX code around the solution found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269273/231499.

My attempt; source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering\settowidth\rotheadsize{Improbable1/}
    \renewcommand\cellalign{cl}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabular}{| >{\bfseries}l | >{\bfseries}c | *{5}{c |} }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}
            {\textbf{\diagbox[height=\rotheadsize]
                {\raisebox{2ex}{Severity}}{\raisebox{10ex}{Likelihood}}}}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Improbable}} 
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Remote}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Occasional}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Probable}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Frequent}}\\ 
        \cline{3-7}
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} \\
        \hline
        Negligible   & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5     \\ \hline
        Minor        & 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10    \\ \hline
        Moderate     & 3 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15   \\ \hline
        Severe       & 4 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20  \\ \hline
        Catastrophic & 5 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However this LaTeX compiles to this (using Overleaf and pdfLaTeX compiler and TexLive v2020):

[image: Compiled LaTeX code]

I am not sure why `\diagbox` is misbehaving in this case where the diagonal line is heavily misplaced. Perhaps I have misunderstood the `height` of `\diagbox`?

Comment: Not tested, but probably you can combine `\Block` and `\diagbox` from the `nicematrix` package to achieve teh desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution consists in inserting the diagbox in the second row, with a negative number of lines and defining the diagbox height more accurately. I think this code yields what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering\settowidth\rotheadsize{Improbable1/}
    \renewcommand\cellalign{cl}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabular}{| >{\bfseries}l | >{\bfseries}c | *{5}{c |} }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Improbable}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Remote}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Occasional}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Probable}}
            & \rotcell{\textbf{Frequent}}\\
        \cline{3-7}
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{-5.9}{*}
         {\textbf{\diagbox[height=\rotheadsize + 2.4\line]
         {\raisebox{0.5ex}{Severity}}{\raisebox{-2ex}{\llap{Likelihood}}}}}}%
     & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} \\
        \hline
        Negligible & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
        Minor & 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\ \hline
        Moderate & 3 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\ \hline
        Severe & 4 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 \\ \hline
        Catastrophic & 5 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the width of the 2nd column of the numerical values (1 to 5) so that the table can be compressed further?

Comment: Yes: it is enough to use `\llap{Likelihood}` so as to make it 0-width for latex. Please see the new snapshot. B.t.w., if your version of latex is comparatively recent, you don't need  to load  `inputenc` any more: utf8 has been the default for nearly two years.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will `inputenc` in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Using `NiceTabular` from `nicematrix` package as suggested by the user, leandriis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Improbable1/}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}l >{\bfseries}c *{5}{c}}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-2}{\diagbox{Severity}{Likelihood}} 
        && \rothead{\textbf{Improbable}} 
        &  \rothead{\textbf{Remote}}
        &  \rothead{\textbf{Occasional}}
        &  \rothead{\textbf{Probable}}
        &  \rothead{\textbf{Frequent}}\\ 
    && \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} \\
    Negligible   & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5     \\
    Minor        & 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10    \\
    Moderate     & 3 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15   \\
    Severe       & 4 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20  \\
    Catastrophic & 5 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, `nicematrix` package have the issue of being unable to adjust it's own version of `diagbox` command such that one can't bold the text using `\textbf` in the `diagbox` and also can't do `\raisebox` command to position the text in the `diagbox` nicely.

Compilation gives:

[image: Compiled LaTeX source code using nicematrix package]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with recent versions of `nicematrix`.

In the `\diagbox`, you can change the positions of both texts by using horizontal skips (eg `\quad`) and struts (vertical rules of width 0 pt inserted with the LaTeX command `\rule`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}l >{\bfseries}c *{5}{c}}[hvlines]
\Block{2-2}
  {
    \diagbox{\bfseries \quad \rule[-3mm]{0pt}{5mm}Severity}
            {\bfseries \rule{0pt}{5mm}Likelihood\quad }
  } 
    & \RowStyle[cell-space-limits=3pt]{\rotate\bfseries} 
    &  Improbable 
    &  Remote
    &  Occasional
    &  Probable
    &  Frequent \\ 
\RowStyle[bold]{}
&& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
Negligible   & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5     \\
Minor        & 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10    \\
Moderate     & 3 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15   \\
Severe       & 4 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20  \\
Catastrophic & 5 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]